# React-Route redirect after socket.io

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sockets, redirect

I am trying to redirect to another path after receiving some information from the server, but It seems I can only use  within , which I am not able to do. 
the flow looks like this
1. client send socket message asking for a path
2. server look up a path, and send it back to client
3. client store the path into redux
4. redirect to the path

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Include some code of what you have attempted and does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's two ways you can redirect using react-router-dom, here's an example.

I suggest taking a look at the react-router docs here https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/philosophy

**Method 1:**
If you have a component that wraps your whole application use `render` and pass props for its arguments example.

https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/docs/api/Route.md#render-func

```
//Wrapping component
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Route} from 'react-router-dom'
//Import your store ex:
{store} from '/path/to/store'

import Child from './components/child'
import Navbar from './components/navbar'
import Footer from './components/footer'

class App extends React.Component {

    render() {
        return(
            <Provider store={store}>
                <Router>
                    <div className="root">
                        <Navbar />
                        <Route exact path="/child" render={props => <Child {...props}/>}
                        //More routes.....
                        <Footer />
                    </div>
                </Router>
            </Provider>
        )

    }
}

//Child component
class SomeComponent extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        socket.on('redirect', url => {
            //dispatch your action to update store then redirect
            this.props.history.push(url)
        })
    }

    render() {
        //some html
    }
}
```

**Method 2:**
Store the redirect path in the store, and check if not null, you can use middleware, but for this example I'll use a simple if statement inside the component, the drawback using this method is you will need to dispatch an action after the redirect(you may run into some redirect issues if you don't) so it may be useful to wrap the redirect inside a method, and dispatch another action to set it back to null.

```
import {Redirect} from 'react-router-dom'

class SomeComponent extends React.Component {
    render() {
        if(this.props.redirectPath) return <Redirect to={this.props.redirectPath} />
        else //Render your component
    }
}
```